# "neunzehnhunderzwölf" oder "neunzehnhundert zwölf"?

Tags: time

zB haben wir das Jahr 1912.

Wie schreibt man das?

> "neunzehnhunderzwölf" oder "neunzehnhundert zwölf"?

Answer (score 5):

Kardinalzahlen werden zusammen geschrieben. Also ist

> neunzehnhundert(und)zwölf

richtig. Allerdings würde man bei einer größeren Zahl eher die Ziffern schreiben: 1912.

https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/wortschatz/zahlen-datum-uhrzeit/kardinalzahlen